# Is it possible to construct an irregularly shaped button that would be an overlay on a map?

Tags: ios, dictionary

The idea is as follows: the view contains a map (can be a zoomable image), map is divided into regions, each region is touchable and takes you to a more detailed view (not a map).

I'm not asking for solutions I'm asking for a general direction, of course if something like this is possible at all.

Comment: For reference, this is my preferred UIButton subclass: https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create transparent images and change hittest method to not account for transparent region. For details see this [link](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2010/03/irregularly-shaped-uibuttons.html).

You can also see [this](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton) project in github.

Comment: touchable area will be bound by the background image?